# how do i get data from the main activity to an intent

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, rss

i am making a rss reader and wanted to take data from the main activity that shows as a card view and place it into a scrolling activity i have already made this and activity. this activity opens when the card view is clicked. i wanted to populate the scroll activity with some data from the rss.
here is the code for my main activity

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
Context context;
public MyAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems){
    this.feedItems=feedItems;
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custum_row_news_item,parent,false);
    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FadeIn).playOn(holder.cardView);
    FeedItem current=feedItems.get(position);
    holder.Title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.Description.setText(current.getDescription());
    holder.Date.setText(current.getPubDate());
    Picasso.with(context).load(current.getThumbnailUrl()).into(holder.Thumbnail);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(context,NewsDetails.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView Title,Description,Date;
    ImageView Thumbnail;
    CardView cardView;
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        Title= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title_text);
        Description= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.description_text);
        Date= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.date_View);
        Thumbnail= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.thumb_img);
        cardView= (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);

    }
}
```

}

here is the code for my rss reader

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
Context context;
String address="http://thirdtryrun.weebly.com/uploads/8/4/8/1/84817908/second.xml";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
URL url;
public ReadRss(Context context,RecyclerView recyclerView){
    this.recyclerView=recyclerView;
    this.context=context;
    progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(context,feedItems);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpace(50));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... Void) {
    ProcessXml(Getdata());
    return null;
}

private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
    if (data!=null) {
        feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
        Element root=data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel=root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items=channel.getChildNodes();
        for (int i=0;i<items.getLength();i++){
            Node currentchild=items.item(i);
            if (currentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                FeedItem item=new FeedItem();
                NodeList itemchilds=currentchild.getChildNodes();
                for (int j=0;j<itemchilds.getLength();j++){
                    Node current=itemchilds.item(j);
                    if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                        item.setTitle(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("Description")){
                        item.setDescription(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                            item.setPubDate(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                        item.setLink(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("content")){
                        item.setContent(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("media:thumbnail")){
                        String url=current.getAttributes().item(0).getTextContent();
                        item.setThumbnailUrl(url);
                    }
                }
                feedItems.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

public Document Getdata(){
    try {
        url=new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream=connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder=builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc= builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

here is the code for my feed item

```
public class FeedItem {
String title;
String link;
String description;
String pubDate;
String thumbnailUrl;
String content;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

public String getThumbnailUrl() {
    return thumbnailUrl;
}

public void setThumbnailUrl(String thumbnailUrl) {
    this.thumbnailUrl = thumbnailUrl;
}

public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}

public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

```
In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);

i.putExtra("key","value");
startActivity(i);
Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("key");
    //The key argument here must match that used in the other activity
}
Use this technique to pass variables from one Activity to the other.
```

Comment: when i do this the getApplicationContext is in red

Answer (score 0):

@Saqib Khalil is on the right track, but if `getApplicationContext()` is giving you problems try: `YourActivity.this` instead.  If you use fragments, you can pass information the same way but replace `YourActivity.this` with `getActivity()`.

Hope this helps!